# Ошибка Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), в чем причина

Tags: php, codeigniter

Не понятно, почему выходит такая ошибка.

```
**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**
```

Вот код

```
foreach($productList as $produсt){
            $tovarniy_product = $this->pages_model->get_class($produсt->id);
            $arrs_tovarniy_class = array();
            foreach ($tovarniy_product as $item){
                              $tovarniy_class = $this->pages_model->get_tovarniy_class_by_id($item['id_tovarniy_class']);
                              $arrs_tovarniy_class[] = (int)$tovarniy_class['title'];
                         }
}
```

Ругается на вот эту строчку

```
foreach ($tovarniy_product as $item){
```

Думал может пустая, Вывовожу переменную через `print_r($tovarniy_product)`

Результат

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_tovarniy_class] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [id_tovarniy_class] => 45 ) [2] => Array ( [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) [3] => Array ( [id_tovarniy_class] => 53 ) [4] => Array ( [id_tovarniy_class] => 54 ) )
```

Что это за ошибка?

Comment: Попробуй добавить проверку на пустоту/массив перед `foreach ($tovarniy_product as $item){` 
Возможно в какой-то момент у тебя приходит пустой массив(или не массив даже)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка **"invalid argument supplied for foreach()"** появляется когда php пытается итерироваться по данным, которые не являются массивом или обьектом.

У вас два цикла. Скорее всего часть элементов формируется нормально, и вы привели пример нормального элемента, чем запутали и себя и нас.
А часть формируется не нормально - возвращает или  boolean или еще что, но точно не обьект или массив.

Добавьте перед вторым циклом:

```
if(!is_array($tovarniy_product)) echo "Ошибка данных.";
```